# How to remote access Aster express through ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, ping, suse, teradata-aster

I am using latest version of Aster express edition form Teradata and configured, which is run only in windows so create a virtual machine of windows on my Ubuntu machine, and its perfectly working in SUSE (using Aster Client Tools - ACT) and windows 7 (Teradata studio).

But I want to use that aster express edition with my UBUNTU(on which window m/c virtually configured , in which my aster express edition is installed) but And when i ping form SUSE to windows and windows to Ubuntu and viceversa,its working but when i ping form Ubuntu to SUSE is shows unreachable.

So my requirement is that i want to access Aster express edition in Ubuntu or remotely in other machine .... Any body HELP!!!

Comment: Maybe better ask this on 'Ask Ubuntu' http://askubuntu.com/ because it does not seem to be about programing.

Comment: @smartmeta thanks for your reply ... but its not only related to Ubuntu. There are many other things.